# How to convert JS array literal from HTML input string to array object without using eval

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to accept JavaScript array literals in an HTML text input.

The problem is that HTML text inputs are captured as strings,  such that an input of `['name', 'who', 1]` becomes `"['name', 'who', 1]"`.

My intention is for the following samples to yield the corresponding outputs.

```
"['river',"spring"]"        //  ["river","spring"]

"[{key:'value'},20,'who']"  //  [{"key":"value"},20,"who"]
```

The way I worked around   the problem is by using  **eval**  in the code snippet below:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form'); 
    const inputField = document.querySelector('.input');
    const btnParse= document.querySelector('.btn'); 
    const out = document.querySelector('.out');  
   
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {   
      e.preventDefault(); 

      try {    
        parsed = eval(inputField.value);

        if(Array.isArray(parsed)) {       
          out.textContent = JSON.stringify(parsed);
        } else throw new Error('input is  not a valid array' );
      } catch(err) {
        out.textContent = `Invalid input: ${err.message}`;
      } 
    });
```

```html
 <form class="form">   
      <fieldset> 
        <legend>Enter array to parse</legend>      
        <input class="input" type="text">      
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="parse">  
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div>   
      <p class="out"> 
      </p> 
    </div>
```

What alternative way is there to converting JavaScript array literal HTML text inputs into JS array objects without using **eval**?

Comment: Replace single quotes with doubles in the string and it then becomes valid json

Answer (score -1):

```
JSON.parse("[1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,78]")
```

Comment: How does this help when the string is `['name', 'who', 1]`? Also always provide a written explanation

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem  JSON.parse would error out if the following string is provided: `"[{name: 'rufus'}]"`

Answer (score -2):

`JSON.parse("[\"name\", \"who\", 1]")` will work for you.

Read about JSON.Parse [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)